# Can I use Vanity name servers for slave zone?

Tags: bind, nameserver

I am new to the whole DNS things but this is what I have done so far.

I have setup a master zone using Bind DNS and I am using zonomi.com to host my salve zone.

Following zonomi's documentation I have created two name servers on my primary zone which are as below:

1. ns1.abc.com //pointed to my VPS server
2. ns2.abc.com //pointed to zonomi's name server

But still I get an error message in zonomi's control panel saying that I am not using their name servers. I have also updated my domain to use these name servers. But can't figure out what I am doing wrong here..

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use "vanity" names, create CNAME records for gandalf.example.com that point to realname.example.com. Don't mess with the way DNS works.